# Why does IntelliJ IDEA throw compilation error?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

Compiling Spark gives this compile error :

[image]

To fix I modify `Utils.classIsLoadable` method to just return `true`:

```
def classIsLoadable(clazz: String): Boolean = {
    // Try { Class.forName(clazz, false, getContextOrSparkClassLoader) }.isSuccess
    true
}
```

I realise this is not a good fix, but so far Spark seems to be running correctly from source. Has this compile error been experienced before and is there a fix? Will returning `true` suffice for now , I'm not sure what impact modifying this return value may have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest compiling Spark from the command-line using Maven or SBT instead of trying to use your IDE's compiler.  Many of the core Spark developers use IntelliJ for editing Spark's source code but still use the command-line compilers, largely because it's been difficult to get the project to build correctly inside IDEs.  Even if you're using an external compiler, you should still be able to benefit from IntelliJ's syntax highlighting, type checking, etc.

Here's a relevant discussion from the Spark developer mailing list: http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/IntelliJ-IDEA-cannot-compile-TreeNode-scala-td7090.html

Note that Spark *users* should be able to use IntelliJ to compile applications that depend on Spark; this issue only affects developers who want to build Spark itself.

If you're interested in fixing the build to work with IntelliJ, I recommend opening a ticket on the [Spark issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK/).